# I am getting undefined reference to `HAL_WWDG_IRQHandler error even after defining #define HAL_WWDG_MODULE_ENABLED in the conf.h file

Tags: stm32, freertos, watchdog

I am working with a project which doesnot have .ioc file from STM32 cube mx, so I have to enable HAL functions and make these changes manually. I wanted to add a watchdog timer. Somehow the HAL_wwdg file is not getting included in the build.

What I have done so far:

1. Enabled wwdg module in conf file
2. I have removed and included the HAL_Driver folder with HAL function includes and source  in Include directories. Similary I have also done the same for folder with conf file.

Could anyone please guide me in understanding the issue?